# Why does awaiting a void function call affect exiting the block?

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), "await" is used to "wait for a Promise", but the
expression following the keyword can also be "any value to wait for", hence not
necessarily a Promise.

In the below demo the awaited value is a call to a void function, i.e. a
function that implicitly returns "undefined". Note: the called function does not
return a Promise. What exactly does it mean to await a void function call?

Demo:
Add keyword "await" to the beginning of line 11, and see how it changes logging
from "FC" to "CF".

```js
"use strict";

function pr() {
  return Promise.resolve(null);
}

function invokeAsyncOperation(cb) {
  pr().finally(cb);
}
async function main() {
  try {
    // demo: await the following statement
    invokeAsyncOperation(() => console.log("C"));
  } catch (e) {} finally {
    console.log("F");
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: "*What exactly does it mean to await a void function call?*" -> "*the expression following the keyword can also be "any value to wait for", hence not necessarily a Promise.*" you answered it yourself. Void functions return `undefined`. It's a value that is not a promise.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, but why does waiting for something that has nothing to wait for, i.e. no future value but only a present value, like in the case of a void function's call, affect the blocks' execution order?

Comment: @jka `await` will always cause an async function to pause.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, but the whole point was that the pause is non existent since the awaited value has no future value. T.J. Crowder below provided the correct answer which is that in this case the JS engine implicitly converts the value to a Promise.

Comment: And thus still pauses for a microtic (at least) before continuing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the result of two things:

1. From the docs you linked:

   > If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's **converted to a resolved Promise**.

   Loosely speaking,¹ `await x` where `x` is not a promise is the same as `await Promise.resolve(x)`. So when you use `await`, there's **always** a promise involved.
2. Promise completion handlers are always called asynchronously, `x` and `await x` have different timing: The former is synchronous; the latter is asynchronous:

   - A promise is created, fulfilled with `x`.
   - `await` puts a completion handler on the promise.
   - Since the promise is already fulfilled, a call to that completion handler is put in the microtask queue to be handled when microtasks are run at the end of the current task.
   - When microtasks are run, the promise completion is reached and does the `console.log`.

You see the log for `C` before the log for `F` because the completion handler logging `C` is already in the microtask queue before the completion handler for `F` is added, so it gets run first.

---

¹ Actually, `Promise.resolve` is always involved, even when `x` is already a promise. But the extra promise gets optimized away if `x` is already a native promise (of the same concrete class). You can see the resolve operation in Step 2 of [the algorithm for `await`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#await).